# How to escape pug's keyword, such as when #{when}

Tags: escaping, pug, keyword

we use pug to compile .pug file into .xml file.

one of xml file are using `<when></when>`

but when I try to add

```
p
   when #{when}
```

pug said when is keyword and syntax is error.

How could I escape keyword `when` in pug file as normal tag like `h1` or `p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html), like this:

```
- let when = 'foo'
p
  #{'when'} #{when}
```

Which compiles to this:

```
<p>
  <when>foo</when>
</p>
```